how to produce message in EmbeddedKafkaBroker where container factory used EmbeddedKafkaBroker in spring boot
I have used EmbeddedKafkaBroker bootstrap server as localhost: 9092 in my @KafkaListener containerFactory, then how can I produce a message to EmbeddedKafkaBroker so that my @KafkaListener annotated method can able print the logs in spring boot.
I have already established a connection between EmbeddedKafkaBroker and containerFactory as a consumer, but couldn't able to produce a message using KafkaTemplat.
I have tried with kafkaproducer.
In my spring boot application i have Kafka consumer config class and Kafka Listener class.
***KafkaConsumerConfig.class***

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("demo.kafka.consumer")
public class KafkaConsumerConfig extends KafkaProperties.Consumer {
    private final String clusterId;

    private final String bootstrapServers;
    private final boolean observationEnabled;
  
    public KafkaConsumerConfig(@Value("${demo.kafka.consumer.cluster.id}") String clusterId,
        @Value("${demo.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers}") String bootstrapServers,
        @Value("${demo.kafka.listener.observation-enabled}") boolean observationEnabled) {
      this.clusterId = clusterId;
      this.bootstrapServers = bootstrapServers;
      this.observationEnabled = observationEnabled;
    }
  
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory() {
      return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(buildProperties(null));
    }
  
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaContainerFactory(
        ConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory,
        ContainerCustomizer<String, String, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String,
            String>> kafkaConsumerCustomizer) {
      ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory
          = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
      factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
      factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory);
      factory.setContainerCustomizer(kafkaConsumerCustomizer);
      factory.getContainerProperties().setObservationEnabled(observationEnabled);
      return factory;
    }
  
    @Bean
    ContainerCustomizer<String, String, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String,
        String>> kafkaConsumerCustomizer() {
      Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
      configs.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers);
      configs.put("clusterId", clusterId);
      configs.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
      return container -> {
        KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin = new KafkaAdmin(configs);
        kafkaAdmin.setClusterId(clusterId);
        container.setKafkaAdmin(kafkaAdmin);
      };
    }
}

******kafkaListener.class*****

@Component
@Slf4j
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class kafkaListener {

  public final KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

  public final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  public kafkaListener(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate,ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
  }

  @KafkaListener(topics = "${demo.topic-name}",
      groupId = "${demo.consumer-group-name}",
      containerFactory = "kafkaContainerFactory")
  public void listenFromTopic(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord,
      Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {

    log.debug("Received message from topic: {}, key: {}, partition: {}, offset: {}",
        consumerRecord.topic(), consumerRecord.key(), consumerRecord.partition(),
        consumerRecord.offset());
    }
 
}

I want to write an integration test where i use EmbeddedKafkaBroker for producing message to the topic where my Kafka listener can listen and the log should print.
I have tried using @EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", kraft = false) but
couldn't able to do that and my listener class also not able to listen . Please give me a solution so My test case should pass.

Please, share your code and what error you have so far.

I have added the code please check it

Looks like you don't rely on the auto-configuration for your consumer side.
You use there some custom property: retina.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers.
We don't see a custom configuration for the producer side. So, apparently, that injected KafkaTemplate comes from the auto-configuration.
The @EmbeddedKafka uses the mentioned spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers Spring Boot property by default. So, it might be the case that KafkaTemplate is auto-configured against EmbeddedKafkaBroker properly.
If your consumer side is still going to use that retina.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers, then you probably can re-map from the spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers in your test configuration, e.g. in the application.properties:
retina.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}


My query is how can I use EmbeddedKafka to produce messages in Kafka topic where container factory is used, and the log should be able to print

You have kafkaTemplate for producing. So, just inject it into your test and produce from there.

I have tried to Autowire but it shows the kafkaTemplate  is null

So, probably your test is not marked with @SpringBootTest, so no ApplicationContext is created for your test environment.
